# Wrong output for "jumping in the clouds" challenge in hackerrank

Tags: c++

I was doing the "[jumping in the clouds](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup)" warm-up challenge with C++, and came up with the following algorithm:

```
int jumpingOnClouds(vector<int> c){
int count=0;
  for(int i=0; i<=c.size();i++ ){
      if(c[i+2]==0){
          count++;
          i=i+1;
      }else if(c[i+1]==0){
          count++;
      }
  }

return count;
}
```

if element i + 2 is equal to 0, then add one to count and add one to index i, otherwise check if element i +1 is equal to zero and add one to array index.

However, every time I run the algorithm, the output is a smaller number than expected:
[Here is an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxSLw.png) 
[Here is an image of the output for the second test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPjyt.png)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=c.size();i++`  -- This has all the signs of causing an out-of-bounds vector access.  Instead of `if(c[i+2]==0){` -- do this: `if(c.at(i+2)==0){`.  Don't be surprised if you get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown.

Comment: What would be the correct way ?, I am something new in C ++

Comment: You cannot access a vector (or array) out of bounds.  Given that information, you should be able to now work out a different way to solve the problem.  You do the same thing here: `else if(c[i+1]==0` -- Change that to: `else if(c.at(i+1)==0` -- Now you will see the entire loop is faulty, thus you won't get any output, thus you will need to rethink how that loop operates.  You were fooled into thinking your solution was "ok" but needed a few adjustments, when it actually is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going 2 steps you are not checking, if it is exceeding the vector size or not.
code -

```
int jumpingOnClouds(vector<int> c) {
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<=c.size();i++ ){
        if(i+2<c.size() && c[i+2]==0){
          count++;
          i=i+1;
        }else if(i+1<c.size() && c[i+1]==0){
          count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your check for the size is done in the wrong order.  You must check the size first -- your code accesses the vector first.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer did not need as many changes as I thought, sorry for the rookie question

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing array out of bound. Since you want to check value at index i+2, you need to make sure that i is strictly inferior to `c.size()-2`:

```cpp
int jumpingOnClouds(vector<int> c){
  int count=0;
  int i = 0;
  for( ; i < c.size()-2; i++){ // you need this condition to not be out of bound
      if (c[i+2]==0) {
          count++;
          i++;
      } else if(c[i+1]==0) {
          count++;
      }
  }
  if (i < c.size() - 1 && c[i+1]==0) // loop might ends up to early, not sure if required by your problem.
     ++count;
  return count;
}
```